# how can i add a popup that is invoked from my appdelegate class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm working on a [google sign in tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) to my ios app and there's a part when we cannot log in user to my app.

So far the code section in appDelegate.swift looks like:

```
guard error == nil && data != nil else {
     // check for fundamental networking error
     print("error=\(error)")

     //lets put popup here that says cant connect to server

     GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
     return
}
```

and now instead of printing the error I want to put the alert popup window. I tried to write there:

```
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but then I'm getting the xcode error near `self.presentViewController` saying that `value of type AppDelegate has no member presentViewController`.

How can I display an alert popup in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Using this line :-

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here you need is a viewController object to present the AlertController, Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I really like a situation when someone says that `you cannot...` and then someone else gives a solution that just works superb :) thanks!

Comment: @N.Raval At me have an error  `self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` . how to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 3**

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: My side still have error, `self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`